# How do write a VBA macro in MS Word to insert a Pie Chart inside a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a VBA macro in MS Word that creates a table with a Pie Chart insert inside a specific cell. The data for the Pie Chart would be requested by the macro. Below is what I have so far but I am having difficulty figuring out how to create the Pie Chart inside the table.

```
Sub InsertChart()
' Inserts a custom chart

Dim data1 As Variant
data1 = InputBox("What was the Moving Water damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")

Dim data2 As Variant
data2 = InputBox("What was the Settlement damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")

Dim data3 As Variant
data3 = InputBox("What was the Pre-Exisiting damage value (enter as 0.0 - 1.0).")


Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
i = i + 1

' Create table if there is more than 1 table
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=2
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 2).Split NumColumns:=3
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Quantity (Measurable Area):"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Description:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Analysis:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "Cause(s) of Damage:"
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = "Recommended Repairs:"

With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
    .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With

Dim small As Boolean
small = False
Dim twoSeries As Boolean
twoSeries = False
Dim pieChart As Boolean
pieChart = True

Dim salesChart As Chart
Dim chartWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet


With ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
    .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With

' Add in a new chart
Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart
Set chartWorkSheet = salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)

' Resize the chart area
chartWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize chartWorkSheet.Range("A1:B4")

' Rename Series 1 as Sales
chartWorkSheet.Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Series 1]]").FormulaR1C1 = "Damage"

' Add data to the chart
chartWorkSheet.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Moving Water"
chartWorkSheet.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "Settlement"
chartWorkSheet.Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "Pre-Exisiting"
chartWorkSheet.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = data1
chartWorkSheet.Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = data2
chartWorkSheet.Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = data3


' Quit Excel, since we no longer need it
salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit

' Put a box around the legend
salesChart.Legend.Format.Line.Visible = msoCTrue

' Fill the background with theme color accent 1
With salesChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Solid
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = wdThemeColorAccent1
End With

' Add a title and format it
salesChart.HasTitle = True
With salesChart.ChartTitle
    .Characters.Font.Italic = True
    .Characters.Font.Size = 18
    .Characters.Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 100)
    .Text = "Damage"
End With


If small Then
' Size and move the chart
With salesChart.Parent
    .Left = 100
    .Width = 300
    .Height = 150
End With
End If

If pieChart Then
' Set chart type
    salesChart.ChartType = xl3DPie
End If

'Move chart to specific cell
ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Select
Selection.Cut

ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(4, 2).Select
Selection.Paste

ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Location:"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
salesChart.CopyPicture
salesChart.Delete
tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Select
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)
Selection.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
```

Add this after the last `End If` and before the `End Sub`

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: The chart has to be inside the cell. When I use your suggested code the chart is floating above. When I try to click and drop the newly created VBA macro chart it doesn't go inside the table either. Thank you for your response.

Comment: salesChart.Delete

returns error "Object doesn't support this action"

Comment: The above is tried and tested. Which MS Office version are you using?

Comment: Hmm, I tested it in Word 2010 and it works just fine as you can see it in the screenshot... Let me see if I can get hands on Off 2007 to test it this weekend.

Comment: How would I edit this if I want to make multiple tables and charts in a word document? This would be a table with 2 Cols and 4 Rows. The second table the chart gets stuck in cell 1,1. I editted the above code to what I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it could be enough for you to put this single line before `End Sub`:

```
salesChart.Parent.ConvertToInlineShape
```

It convert chart from shape to inlineshape which will be located inside your table.
I did test it for empty document and it do what you want.

You could add this line later to autofit cell/column:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).AutoFit
```

**EDIT** conversion to certain cell in table 1.

Do this conversion this way:

```
Dim InSHP As InlineShape
Set InSHP = salesChart.Parent.ConvertToInlineShape
InSHP.Range.Cut
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(4, 2).Range.Paste
```

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to have the InlineShape be created in a specific cell of a table? Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(4, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart is not working.